# Flutter Custom SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

I would like to understand if there's a way to make the default sliver app bar in flutter to look more like this design I found online.

[image]

PS: I am familiar with the default way of doing this but to make use of flutter's extensively customizable widgets in this scenario seems to be the issue.

Here's what I've done. Can't seem to have a way to round the bottom edges or achieve the non-default sliver app bar behavior.

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          expandedHeight: height * 0.35,
          pinned: false,
          floating: true,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.chevron_left,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20.0), bottomRight: Radius.circular(20.0))
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    'https://picsum.photos/200',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: width,
                    height: height * 0.35,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
        ),
        SliverFillRemaining(
          child: Column(
            children: List<int>.generate(6, (index) => index)
                .map((index) => Container(
                      height: 40,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('$index item'),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: tried `SliverPersistentHeader`?

Comment: I had a similar requirement before, and this video help me a lot, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mz3kHQxBjGg

Comment: Yes, I have gotten the rounded shape and behavior with SliverPersistentHeader but unfortunately, the sliverlist scrolls behindthe header instead of with it and just below it.

Answer (score 0):

One option that you can try is using a [`ContinuousRectangleBorder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ContinuousRectangleBorder-class.html) or [`RoundedRectangleBorder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RoundedRectangleBorder-class.html) it will help you shape the corner of the [`SliverAppBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html):

Example for `ContinuousRectangleBorder`

```
SliverAppBar(
  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
      topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
      topRight: Radius.circular(30),
    ),
  ),
),
```

And will result in something like this:

[image]

`RoundedRectangleBorder`

```
SliverAppBar(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
  ),
),
```

[image]